# MPI multiples Isends, Irecvs with waitany is a good approach?

Tags: mpi, deadlock

Is there any problem using the below code on a MPI project? Can it possibly generate deadlocks or buffer overlaps?

```cpp
//send a data to all nodes on receiver list
for (auto &e : receivers_list) {
        MPI_Request request;
        MPI_Isend( &data, 1, MPI_INT, e.remot_id , 1234 , MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
}

//read data from senders
MPI_Request request_arr[senders_list.size()];
for (auto &e : senders_list) {
        MPI_Irecv  (&data, 1, MPI_INT, e.remot_id, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request_arr[request_index++]);
}

//wait for all receives complete 
for (int count_recv = 0; count_recv < senders_list.size(); ++count_recv) {
        MPI_Waitany(senders_list.size(), request_arr, &request_index, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

     //do some code here ....
}
```

Comment: All of your `data` arrays are going to be mangled doing it this way. You need to ensure you have `senders_list.size()` different arrays for you to receive the data into *as well as* the sending array `data`.

Comment: Why not just use Waitall instead of a loop over Waitany?

Comment: You need to wait on receivers_list somewhere, preferably in concert with senders_list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in the code snippet you posted, which I'll try to detail here:

- The non-blocking sending and receiving call are using the same `data` buffer. This is very very wrong, and this at two levels:

  1. Since the calls are made within an loop, each new call will create yet another reading or writing on the same memory address. Then, you'll have plenty of race conditions as for the order in which these will be completed, leading to undefined behaviour.
  2. Even if the above point wasn't an issue in itself, the MPI standard clearly states that accessing a communication buffer which is used for a non-blocking MPI communication, before this one has been proven completed (with `MPI_Wait()` or `MPI_Test()` etc) is forbidden. Actually, this pretty much is a way of preventing the sort of race conditions described in my first point, but that means that the code is not only of undefined behaviour, it is also wrong from a MPI standard perspective.
- Your calls of `MPI_Isend()` in the first loop always reuse the same `request`, overwriting its value at each iteration. This means that you lose any handle on the previous call, preventing you from forcing their completion, and potentially leaking memory inside the MPI library. You should use an array of requests instead, as you did in the receiving loop.
- For dealing with the requests, you should also include the sending part, to make sure both the sending and the receiving sides of the communications progress equally...
- Finally, and that's an arguable detail, it is usually better performance wise to post receiving requests before sending ones, to have the MPI library ready for receiving incoming messages rather than dealing with unexpected ones. Therefore, swapping the sending and receiving loops might be a good idea.

This is what the code could therefore look like:

```cpp
MPI_Request request_arr[receivers_list.size() + senders_list.size()];
int request_index = 0;

//read data from senders
int dataRecv[senders_list.size()];
for ( auto &e : senders_list ) {
    MPI_Irecv( &dataRecv[request_index], 1, MPI_INT, e.remot_id, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request_arr[request_index++] );
}

//send a data to all nodes on receiver list
for ( auto &e : receivers_list ) {
    //I assume that you want to send the same value to all processes here, so like doing a MPI_Bcast()
    MPI_Isend( &data, 1, MPI_INT, e.remot_id, 1234 , MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request_arr[request_index++] );
}

//wait for all receives complete 
for ( int count_req = 0; count_req < request_index; ++count_req ) {
    int curr_idx;
    MPI_Waitany( request_index, request_arr, &curr_idx, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );

    if ( curr_idx < senders_list.size() ) {
        //the completed request is a receiving one
        //we can therefore freely access dataRecv[curr_idx]
        //do some code here ...
    }
}
```